# CSS float attribute for a sidebar (I can use tables if necessary)

Tags: html, css, css-float

Ok I am having trouble with a school project where we must create a website with 5 pages, and publish it one of the requirements is a sidebar on every page, but the problem is we are not allowed to use absolute positioning only float and tables can be used to do this.
Here is my External CSS
    /* CSS Document */

```
body{
background-color: #181818;
color: #E60000;
}
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000080;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#body{
/*this is here for only a certain part of the body*/
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    margin-left: 0.7%;
    margin-right: 39%;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;

}
#sidebar{
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    margin-right: 0.7%;
    margin-left: 65%;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;

}
p{
    line-height: 160%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    Padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
/*Navigation bar*/
ul{
    background-color: #000080;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
}
ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li a:link, ul li a:visited{
    color: darkred;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul li.selected{
    background-color: #181818;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<div id="body">
<h1 id="header">About me</h1>
<p>some stuff
<br>
<br>other stuff</p>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Me</h2>
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
<p style = "text-align: center;">
stuff<br>
br>Much more stuff</p>
</div>



<div id="sidebar"><h1>Name here</h1>
<p>Even more stuff</p>
</div>
```

Alright that is all the code I used for this I hope this helps

(sry this isn't codded correctly based on the websites standards but I couldn't get it to work sry)
alright Now Either I can get both #sidebar and #body's divs to appear in the same location; however one of there text will be below the other div container or one div will appear below the other on one side of the page, and I know this isn't very good CSS it's just a rough outline, but this is the biggest problem that stands out to me that will be hard to fix, so if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please share your HTML as well (paraphrased to just reproduce the issue you are having)

Comment: I could not quite understand your problem, please Share your html, or post an example in jsFiddle

Comment: Done hope this helps this is without most of the bulk inside the tags

Comment: Actaully hold on something didn't work correctly

Comment: Ok now it is done sry im still getting used to this site

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

You can set the main content section - i believe you use #body - to have a width of e.g 70% and then the sidebar to have a width of 30%. Then use `float: left;` on both the elements.

Keep in mind that the 70/30 does not factor in padding or margins, which you will need to account for.

the code could look like this

```
> #body{    width: 60%;     background-color: blue;     float: left;    height: 200px; }
> #sidebar{     width: 20%;     background-color: red;  float: left;    height: 200px; }
> 
> 
> 
> <div id="body"></div> <div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i tried to reproduce your issue in a Fiddle here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u5ku5jc9/2/)**

You have quite a few CSS issues:

- if you want to use float for your layout, both can be float left with widths set
- you are mixing percentages in your margin (which i converted to width
  values) and pixel values in your padding
- you can use the universal selector to set the box-sizing to
  'border-box' which does not add the padding values to the width
  values (* { box-sizing: border-box; }) -- if you don't use this CSS
  you need to be careful that your padding doesn't cause your elements
  to become wider than 100% of the page (their parent element

Here is your CSS after my modifications.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000080;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#body{
/*this is here for only a certain part of the body*/
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebar{
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    width: 35%;    
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2gupoxg1/1/)**

**CSS**

```
body{
background-color: #181818;
color: #E60000;
}
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000080;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#body{
/*this is here for only a certain part of the body*/
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;

}
#sidebar{
    background-color: #000080;
    border: 5px inset #C0C0C0;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width:20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;

}
p{
    line-height: 160%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    Padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Heh well its rough but its working, and also sorry for my horrible grammar I'm just a bit stressed out considering that the first part is due tomorrow.

Comment: @Codingfail i have just aligned what you tried. If you want make it as better UI I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming body is where you're putting your content (not the html body tag with an id of body)

Anyways when you have two side by side containers you will want both with the same float.

Example

```
#body, #sidebar {
    Float: right;
    Padding: 2%; 
}
#body {
    Width: 70%;
}
#sidebar {
    Width: 15%;
}
```

example values just make sure the width + margins + padding don't don't exceed 100% or the parent container max pixel width.

```
Box-sizing: Border-box;
```

can help with containers growing with padding or borders.

Comment: I guess I was a bit slow typing this up on an iPad :/